# Identity 2.1, asynchronous programming, and updating additional user data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-identity-2

I understand what asynchronous programming is, but I have a hard time actually implementing it in my code.  Identity 2.1 generates the CRUD methods and I want to add some code to it.  How can I get the LINQ update to save?  Do I need to use await?  The AspNetUsers table updates fine, but not my UserProfiles table:

```
// POST: /Users/Edit/5    [Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,Email,Id,Address,City,State,PostalCode")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel editUser, params string[] selectedRole)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            user.UserName = editUser.Email;
            user.Email = editUser.Email;
            user.Address = editUser.Address;
            user.City = editUser.City;
            user.State = editUser.State;
            user.PostalCode = editUser.PostalCode;

            var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

            selectedRole = selectedRole ?? new string[] { };

            var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());



            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
            result = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, userRoles.Except(selectedRole).ToArray<string>());

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
            //Update Firstname/Lastname
            var dbEntry = db.UserProfiles.Single(x => x.UserId == editUser.Id);
            dbEntry.FirstName = editUser.FirstName;
            dbEntry.LastName = editUser.LastName;
            db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed.");
        return View();
    }
```

Since my post was put on hold, let me explain my question in more detail.  The var dbEntry is not updating on the db.SaveChanges().  When I step through the code, the editUser.FirstName and editUser.LastName does have a value.

var dbEntry does have a record to be updated.  Again, db.SaveChanges() does not save.

I think what is happening is something with asynchronous programming.  Since the method is public async Task Edit()

instead of:

public ActionResult Edit().  The update will work using public ActionResult Edit().

Since I'm not use to asynchronous programming (which I'm learning), how do I implement await in this method so var dbEntry will update?

Comment: So what problem are you having with the code shown?

Comment: var dbEntry never saves.

Comment: Are you sure SaveChanges is being called?  Have you stepped into it with the debugger?

Comment: Yes, I stepped through the code and it doesn't break, it just keeps on stepping line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asynchronous aspect should not be a problem. The `ApplicationDbContext` of your `UserManager` is out-of-the-box configured with `AutoDetectChangesEnabled == true`. Chances are that your second DbContext is not. Turn it on if you like, or explicitly set `db.Entry(dbEntry).State = EntityState.Modified` before calling `Save`.

Comment: Gotcha!   Thanks Oskar!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sort of sidesteps the question altogether, but why in the world are you using a separate entity to track profile data? One of the primary reasons Identity exists is to provide a more extensible user management system, meaning you don't have to try to tack on functionality like you used to have to with ASP.NET Membership.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // everything else already here

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, just update it along with the user instance you're already updating:

```
user.UserName = editUser.Email;
user.Email = editUser.Email;
user.Address = editUser.Address;
user.City = editUser.City;
user.State = editUser.State;
user.PostalCode = editUser.PostalCode;
// add these
user.FirstName = editUser.FirstName;
user.LastName = editUser.LastName;
```

What's even more confusing is that `ApplicationUser` had already been extended in this way, because Address, City, State, and PostalCode are not on `IdentityUser`. Why you started handling first and last name information in a different way, then, is beyond me.

Comment: It's not my call.  I the inherited the database and the UserProfile table holds about 40 columns.

Comment: You can refactor. The fact that you inherited bad code is no excuse to just keep using it.

Comment: I agree, but that doesn't answer the question why the update never executes.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, some people work on a world that can't be changed by them. They have to adapt to that world. Maybe because there are a lot of applications already using that database. Maybe because it's a close product you are interacting with. ASP.NET Identity 2 is very good for doing what it does and lets everyone else out to dry. There's an excessive obsession on storing stuff and interoping was totally left out.